# Searching files using id in php

Tags: php, file

I created a website, and on it the users can upload different files which they can later access through their profiles.  Over time, I realized that this method of creating folders and sub-folder for users and is quite cumbersome, as it creates so many folder and sub-folders as more users join and use my website.  I'm now thinking of having one folder for all the files but renaming user's files on the fly to something like `USERID-FILENAME`.

The problem comes when I want to display the files to their specific user; I want to search the files in the folder then grab the files that start with a particular userid e.g if its user of id 200, I want to grab all files that have 200 before the first hyphen and display them.

How can I accomplish this and is it the best method to use?

Comment: This looks like a job for a database!  Store the file names and user ids in a database.  That way you can quickly lookup which files belong to which user.

Comment: ...and soon you will run into performance issues for having million of files in single catalog. Use database.

Comment: Seconding Rocket's recommendation for using the database to store the path. You have a simple table, say `user_files`, with columns ID, user_id, and path. That way, you don't have to iterate over irrelevant data (other users's files) just to find what you're after, and you make it easier to change the base path in the future.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, David and Chris will using the database affect scalability in future?

Comment: @LutaV: Using a database will make it so you *can* scale the app in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something more like a database or a key-value store for this work, rather than your file-system, which will not scale well as/if your site grows significantly.

For example, you could use something like `<userid>-<filename>` as a key in a key-value store, with the contents of the file set as the value, encoded as a binary blob.

On top of this, you may then need a descriptor that keeps track of all the files a user has ever uploaded, perhaps keyed directly by the userid or by something like, `<userid>-files`

Then when you're looking up the user, you load their `<userid>-files` descriptor first, using this to present a list of files they access/control/own, then lookup `<userid>-<filename>` when they request a specific file.

Thinking on this some more, that may not be sufficient to handle cases of a user uploading the same file multiple times -- you might want to assign IDs to the files themselves, and just keep those IDs in the `<userid>-files` blob. This has the added advantage that the schema for storing files is user-agnostic, so you could start extending your service to implement sharing functionality (with perhaps another hunk of data describing sharing/access-control properties).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
foreach (glob( ((int)'$userid')'-*') as $file) {
    process($file);
}
```